# Relacionamento 1 - 1

Tags: sql, modelo-relacional, relacionamento

estou com um pouco de dificuldade em desenhar meu modelo relacional de banco de dados.

**A ideia segue o seguinte principio:**

- Teria um sistema de login, e para isso uma tabela **usuario**
- Também teriam 3 tipos de pessoas que fariam login no sistema **produtores, fornecedores e clientes**
- Um fornecedor tem relação com outra tabela chamada **endereco**
- E um produtor tem relação com outra tabela chamada **dados_bancarios**

Pelo que vi, são todas relações de **1 para 1** porém não consigo identificar a melhor forma de reproduzir um modelo relacional para o problema  descrito.

**O que fiz até agora:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não sei se o que fiz esta certo nem se a ligações estão corretas, lembro-me de alguns conceitos falado por o professor sobre cardinalidades fracas, fortes e outras coisas do tipo e tentei aplicar aqui esses conceitos, mas possa ser que eu não os domine ainda.

Alguém pode me explicar qual a melhor forma de resolver este problema que passei, e também explicar de forma geral o porque de ser de tal jeito? Agradeço a todos desde já!

Comment: Me parece que seus relacionamentos sejam necessariamente 1:1 ou todos os clientes serão necessariamente fornecedores? Se puder ser ou cliente ou fornecedor então um dos relacionamentos poderá não existir. (supondo que quando você especifica 1 num relacionamento está querendo dizer obrigatoriamente 1).

Comment: Note que não tem muito sentido criar relacionamentos 1:1 no modelo conceitual. No modelo físico sim podemos querer separar por tipo de informação.

Comment: Pode-se ter mais de uma conta bancária e mais de um endereço , por exemplo a fábrica para entrega de mercadorias  fica num local e o escritório para entrega de notas em outro , existe razão para limitar o 1:1 ?

Answer (score 0):

Cara, tenho duas coisas para te falar. A primeira é que não existe melhor forma de criar um modelo relacional. A segunda é que não existe certo e errado. Quando se trata de modelo relacional, você tem sim alguns conceitos e técnicas que te ajudam a construir um que fiquei manutenível e elegante, mas não significa que se você não segui-los, vai estar errado.

---

Alguns pontos que eu posso observar do seu modelo que você pode melhorar:

1. Sua entidade cliente só tem uma chave primária e uma chave estrangeira. Não faz muito sentido você ter uma entidade para guardar nenhuma informação. A não ser que seja uma entidade associativa, como é o caso da sua entidade "produtor".
2. Ao criar uma entidade, você pode pensar da seguinte forma (me ajuda bastante, não sei se irá te ajudar): A sua entidade "usuário" por exemplo. Fique sabendo que, já que você colocou "nome" como atributo dessa entidade, não existirá uma pessoa, no seu modelo, que não seja usuário, pois você não conseguirá dar nome a ela, já que esse atributo é de usuário. Então o que eu faria seria criar uma entidade pessoa, que se relaciona com o usuário numa relação 1 para 1. Essa entidade pessoa teria o atributo nome.
3. Procure sobre boas práticas de modelagem, principalmente para abreviações, tipagem e letras maiúsculas/minúsculas. Evita redundância e confusão na hora de voltar ao modelo depois de um tempo. Infelizmente não tenho nenhuma fonte para te indiciar, pois não leio sobre isso há algum tempo, mas acredito que ainda se preza por esses padrões.
4. Email é um atributo que eu separaria em uma entidade. Assim como você fez com Endereco. O email tem um endereço, um serviço (gmail, hotmail, etc), entre outros.

Comment: Obrigado pelas dicas João Victor, com certeza vou analisar tudo que você falou e aplicar em meus modelos futuros.

Comment: Eu achei a sua resposta sinceramente muito muito mas, muito doida. Há contradições ... então é complicado dizer que sim ou que não.